# Visiting the U.K. for three months will I have issues at IO?

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, us-citizens, visa-free-entry

So I’m in a long distance relationship and I’ll be visiting my boyfriend for 3 months. I’ve been in the U.K. before with no issue but that was only for two weeks.

I’m a single person. I have a dog, I work temp with aspects of other jobs lined up for me when I come back plus I’ll be enrolling in a local college. 
I have funds, my boyfriend is a full time professional and my dad offered to give me extra money if I need anything though my money will only be used for odd date nights. I’ll be staying with my boyfriend I’m just afraid they’ll think I want to stay.

I have a return ticket, I’m going to be bringing bank information, the proof that I have work available for me when I return, and my boyfriend write me an invitation letter. What else should I have? I’m worried I’ll be denied or detained because it’s for such a long time. Am I over reacting? I’ve been freaking myself with horror stories and it’s giving me anxiety

Comment: What is your citizenship (and country of residence if different)?

Comment: When you say "I've been in the UK before", was that to visit your boyfriend or for some other reason?

Comment: I’ve visited my boyfriend for two weeks and was honest about everything coming in. I’m from the US

Answer (score 3):

> What else should I have?

Evidence showing where you live in the US and where you'll be living when you return.  It's probably best if that is the same place.  It's also helpful if you own or lease the place yourself and have the documents to show it.

> I’m worried I’ll be denied or detained because it’s for such a long time. Am I over reacting?

It's hard to say.  If you're detained, at least, it will only be as long as is necessary to put you on a plane back to the US.

As you probably know, visitors to the UK are allowed to stay for as long as six months, so the duration of your stay is not inherently a problem.  You could indeed have a problem convincing the immigration officer that you are a "genuine visitor."

Your circumstances include some red flags, so you are right to be concerned.  Being a temporary worker could increase suspicion that you will seek freelance work in the UK.  On the other hand, it makes your plan to spend three months in the UK more credible than it would be if you were a full-time long-term employee.

If your income is sufficient that you can forego it for three months comfortably, that will help, but given your mention of support from your father and that your boyfriend is a full-time professional, it seems that your income may not be that high.

Another thing you should be aware of is that the UK officers are supposed to make sure that any money you claim is legitimately yours to use.  If you rely on your father's money, you should have a statement from him that he does not expect you to repay it.  You should also be prepared to present *his* bank statements to show that he acquired the money legitimately.

If you have time before you travel, you may want to consider applying for a [standard visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa), even though you are not required to have one.  This would allow you to make your case in the privacy of your own home rather than in a busy airport immigration hall.  Having the visa does not guarantee entry, but it does limit the degree to which the immigration officer will investigate you, since the visa shows that you have already been investigated.  This approach should alleviate some of your anxiety.

If you do not have time to apply for the visa, you should nonetheless read the guidance and prepare the same documents that you would for an application.  Bring them with you so you can show them to the immigration officer if necessary.

Finally, you probably should not volunteer them until it becomes apparent that the officer is concerned.  You don't want to appear like you're hiding something.  So be prepared to answer in detail, but don't offer the detail unless asked.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer. I wasn’t expecting my dad to help out because I was going to do it all on my own. But he recently told me he’d give me some extra cash every so often. I mentioned that and my boyfriend so that people wouldn’t worry I didn’t have a place to be. I’ll keep in mind not to give more information than needed but to also be honest and have documentation ready just in case. I unfortunately don’t have enough time for a visa, but I’ll remain honest and hopeful ☺️

Comment: @Bekah I agree with everything phoog said. In addition I recommend you have your boyfriend's mobile number to hand. If you are detained for a more indepth interview, the IO may want to call him and ask him a few questions. Be aware that in this circumstance the IO will ask you both questions and will compare your answers, and may ask both of you trick questions like "Are you looking forward to being married?" to see if one of you is hiding anything. I think in your situation it's unlikely but possible you'd be detained, and you should prepare for the possibility.

Comment: UPDATE! I got in  I was nervous coming to IO, but I was honest. He seemed nice enough even smiled at the fact we met before. IO stamped my visa for 6 months I’ll be staying little over three months. I think my return ticket and the fact that I have to go home to help my dad after surgery helped. He didn’t look at any documents, but I’m glad I came prepared! Thanks everyone ☺️☺️